# After few hours of running the moveit program, the program is killed

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to implement Reinforcement Learning within ROS for a KUKA manipulator. Therefore, I need to let run program for a day in order to learn the KUKA manipulator accomplish certain task. However, after few hours the program is killed with this error messages:

`ERROR: Failed to fetch current robot state`

`INFO: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestep within 1 second. Check clock synchronization if you are running ROS across multiple machines!`

To provide more info: I am using Gazebo simulator with a small cube and the task is to push the object into the goal location. Regarding to Moveit, I am using TrackIK solver and I generate [x,y,z] coordinates from the neural network directly to trajectory_controller using `setFromIK` function.

I am using:

> ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(2);
> spinner.start();

so this should not be a problem. I have already tried increase number of threads but its not working. Could someone point me to the right direction? This is the problem why the learning process is failing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346242/after-few-hours-of-running-the-moveit-program,-the-program-is-killed/) by [Zenzu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32843/zenzu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by using tf2 instead of tf library.

---

Originally posted by [Zenzu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32843/zenzu/) with karma: 28 on 2020-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1